# LLVM Insert function call into another function

Tags: c++, llvm

I am trying to insert function call inside a main function, so then when i run generated binary file, function will be executed automatically. Since language i am trying to "compile" looks like a "scripted" language  :

```
function foo () begin 3 end;
function boo () begin 4 end;

writeln (foo()+boo()) ;
writeln (8) ;
writeln (9) ;
```

where writeln is a function available by default, and after executing binary i expect to see 7 8 9. Is there a way to insert last function call right before return statement of a main function ?
Right now I have

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}
```

and i want to have something like

```
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  %calltmp = call double @writeln(double 7.000000e+00)
  %calltmp = call double @writeln(double 8.000000e+00)
  %calltmp = call double @writeln(double 9.000000e+00)
  ret i32 0
}
```

editing IR file manually and compile it afterwards works, but i want to do it in codegen part of my code.

edit

what i generate right now is

```
define double @__anon_expr() {
entry:
  %main = call double @writeln(double 3.000000e+00)
  ret double %main
}

define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}
```

so when i execute binary - nothing happens

Comment: How is this related to `c++`?

Comment: @super I am writing frontend of llvm in c++

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're trying to do. If it is the IR you're generating anyway, you can do whatever you like. If you want to modify some existing IR - that's probably not what you should be doing. If you still insist, then just write a function pass and run it with `opt`.

Comment: @SK-logic I am generating IR, but i don't know how to add function calls inside a main function. Right now the look like this 
```
define double @__anon_expr() {
entry:
  %main = call double @writeln(double 3.000000e+00)
  ret double %main
} 
define i32 @main() {
entry:
  ret i32 0
}
``` 
so nothing is executed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

feel free to source your inspiration from here

```
Type * returnType = Type::getInt32Ty(TheContext);
std::vector<Type *> argTypes;
FunctionType * functionType = FunctionType::get(returnType, argTypes, false);
Function * function = Function::Create(functionType, Function::ExternalLinkage, "main", TheModule.get());

    BasicBlock * BB = BasicBlock::Create(TheContext, "entry", function);
    Builder.SetInsertPoint(BB);
    vector<Value *> args;
    args.push_back(ConstantFP::get(TheContext, APFloat(4.0)));
    Builder.CreateCall(getFunction("writeln"), args, "call");
    Value * returnValue = Builder.getInt32(0);
    Builder.CreateRet(returnValue);
```